# Signal from cloud to internal network

Tags: c#, azure, messaging

We have a microservice based application/ website hosted currently in Azure, and we need to have a function where we press on a button, and it sends some data to another webservice currently hosted inside our corporate network.

Our IT bods are against being able to POST to a service hosted inside our network, and I am wondering how people normally deal with this problem.

I can think of 2 possible solutions, neither of which I like particularly:

1. Set up a VPN to the internal network, which feels a bit of a heavy solution to me
2. The internal network service polls the cloud application for changes of state continuously, an triggers an update process when a change is recorded. This will generate a lot more traffic than I would ideally want

How do other people address this issue? Essentially I just want to send some data from the cloud into our network in a **secure** fashion. Pulls from our network are OK, but pushes into it are not.
Even sending a signal to get the internal network to initiate a pull would also work fine.

Comment: We abstract out internal APIs behind API gateways which run in a DMZ, then third party services can post to the gateway using an API key, which authenticates and forwards the request to the internal API. Not sure whether that's something that would suit your scenario though.

Answer (score 1):

Both the solutions you came up with are fairly common patterns in Azure architecture. Of the two, the second would be the one I would generally choose for this particular scenario, but it does depend on how fast you need the push to happen. VPN is going to be the fastest as you have a direct connection between your Azure service and your internal one, but it is a bit more complex to set up for a single pipeline.

The second is generally accomplished through a messaging service like [Service Bus](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-bus/) as it adds a lot of resiliency to that sort of arrangement. You can configure your onprem service to ping Service Bus based on the interval you define- more often if you need the updates to happen quickly, less often if you want to reduce traffic. Depending on the size of the data, you can load it directly into Service Bus for pickup or the message can contain the location of the required data. [Event Grid](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/event-grid/) is another option for a messaging service. It sends notifications out instead of waiting for you to poll, so it would be a good choice if you wanted to ping your onprem service to reach out and pick up the changes.

If you are open to using Logic Apps to do the push, it accesses onprem resources via a [data gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install) that you install inside your network. It does use Service Bus in the background to accomplish this so you will be using your second solution, but it would be a bit simpler from a development perspective.